# How to create a common frontend for multiple microservices in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, user-interface, frontend, microservices

I've been reading up on microservices for a bit and started to develop some small services in ASP.NET web framework in the MVC pattern. What I'm struggling to figure out though is, how to create a shared UI for these services?

Currently every microservice has their own views and css, but I'd like a common frontend so I can use a single css for every service.

I'd be happy about any ideas on how to approach this problem, book recommendations to read up on it or maybe some example applications. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see there is no consensus on the best way of doing this securely, but I have worked in an org that used this pattern:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/architect-microservice-container-applications/microservice-based-composite-ui-shape-layout

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using .Net MVC template that would create View and CSS . Microsservices are normally WebAPIs. Frontend (MVC or Single Page App) will use those Web APIs over http to render UI.

So you need to create a single front-end be it Single Page Application using Angular/ReactJs or Web view using .Net MVC.  The front-end will query the backend microservices to retrieve the data and render UI.